# Sencha Touch Reset combobox after doQuery

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I use onBeforequery on à combobox. Works als it should, but:
I want to reset the combo box after sending data to server.

How do I reset after a doQuery??

```
onBeforequery: function (record) {
    record.query = new RegExp(record.query, 'i');
    record.forceAll = true;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [this method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-reset).

You should just be able to append that to whatever logic you use to submit the data.

Good Luck, Brad